# Partially assigning a vector to another

Tags: c++, vector, stl

`std::fill( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value )` allows me to fill a part of a *vector* with a constant value.

`std::assign( InputIt first, InputIt last )` allows me to *completely* replace a *vector* with a part of another vector.

Is there a function in the STL that combines these two (smt like `part_assign(begin, end, begin, end)`) that allows me to fill an interval of a vector with another vector?

If not, what would be the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: Where do you get this `std::assign` from?

Comment: @JonathanWakely he is probably thinking of [`std::vector::assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's called `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(src_begin, src_end, dst_begin);
```

It copies `std::distance(src_begin, src_end)` elements (from your source vector) to the elements beginning at `dst_begin` (in your destination vector). Just as with `fill`, the destination iterator may be an inserter if you want to mutate the receiving container.

There are several variations, e.g.

```
std::copy_n(src_begin, n, dst_begin);
```

which copies `n` elements. There is also `std::move` that moves elements rather than copy them, or you can use move iterators with `copy`.

Comment: As far as I can see, `copy` inserts the elements in the vector. What I am looking for is a function that replaces the elements in a vector, beginning from some iterator, with a sequence of other elements.

Comment: @RobertHönig: Yes, I understand. You are looking for `std::copy`.

Comment: _"As far as I can see, `copy` inserts the elements in the vector."_ No it doesn't. It performs the assignment `*(dst_begin+i) = *(src_begin+i)` for every `i` from 0 to `std::distance(src_begin, src_end)`. That doesn't insert any new elements into the vector _unless_ `dst_begin` is a `back_insert_iterator` into the vector. It just assigns new values to existing elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are three such methods in the class template `std::vector`. They are

```
iterator insert(const_iterator position, size_type n, const T& x); 
template <class InputIterator> 
iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last); 
iterator insert(const_iterator position, initializer_list<T> il);
```

It seems that the most suitable method for your task is

```
template <class InputIterator> 
iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 0, 1, 1, 0 };

    std::vector<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 };

    v1.insert( std::next( v1.begin(), 2 ), 
               std::next( v2.begin(), 1 ), 
               std::prev( v2.end(), 1 ) ); 

    for ( int x : v1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

At least as I understand the question, you're asking for something where (for example) I can have an input vector like:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

and I want to replace the piece `3, 4, 5` with different data--say `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`, so after the operation, the result should be: `[1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 6]`. Particularly, I'm assuming that the old piece and the new piece are *not* necessarily the same length.

Assuming that's correct, then the short is is: "no". As in, no, neither `std::vector` nor the standard algorithms directly support doing that.

The simple way to do it would be to use `vector::erase` to erase the original data, then use `vector::insert` to insert the new data.

For (possibly) improved efficiency, you's start by finding the shorter of the two (the old piece or the new piece). Then you'd copy that length of data from the new data over the old data. Then, if the new was larger than the old, you'd insert the remainder of the new data. Otherwise (the new was smaller than the old) you'd erase the remainder of the old data.